# Rails 4 Form - Adding a new input to an existing record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where users enter profile info which is saved in the User model. I need to collect another piece of information from users at a later stage (on a different page). How do I collect this info and append it to the existing user record?

Here is my form code with the one additional input I need from the user. When I hit submit, it runs without error but the new field is not saved in my model. I ran the migration to add the field to the model.

```
<%= form_for @user, html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>

 <div class="form-group">
  <%= f.label :what_is_your_favorite_color %>
  <%= f.text_field :color, class:"form-control" %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class:"btn btn-primary" %>
 </div>

<% end %>
```

My controller update method is currently blank .. can you tell me what the update method should look like? The user is logged in so I need to find that user record (probably by id column?) and write or update the new input into the model.

```
def update
   ??    
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to fetch your record, the pass it the params hash, and Rails will do the rest.

```
def update
  @record = Record.find(params[:id])
  if @record.update(record_params)
    redirect_to @record
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

If you are using Rails 4, you need to account for `strong_parameters`. So add the new attribute to the permitted attributes.

```
  def record_params
    params.require(:record).permit(:color, :and, :other, :attributes, :go, :here)
  end
```

The above code assumes that the record id will be in the params hash, or in other words, you are using RESTful routes. If you are not, you may want to pass in the id from the session (if this is, as you say, a user record, and you are using Devise).

```
def update
  @record = Record.find(current_user)
  # ... the rest should be the same
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I use Devise for authentication so the model includes fields like password, last_sign_in_date etc. Do I need to include those in the permitted attributes as well?

Comment: Yes, if you want to reuse your controller method to update the user from different forms. So, if you have multiple forms submitting to the same controller action, yes, you do.

Comment: My user controller doesn't have def record_params. I'm assuming it is handled by the devise gem. Should I just add the code as you suggest? Or should I add the new field in the gem code?

Comment: When I run your code above, I get an error `could not find User without an ID`. What does that mean?

Comment: It means you are probably not using RESTful routes, which you should be. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Now I get the error `param not found: user`. In this case, I'm not using RESTful routes because the rest of the controller actions are handed by devise. I'm just creating this one specific method. I'm sure there are better ways to it but I'm new so I'm figuring it out.

Comment: Well, it's up to you. You have to decide how you want to pass the id to the `User.find` method. Rails needs to load the user. To load it, it needs an `id`. This id can be either in the url (params) or from a method like `current_user`. I'm not sure what your setup is like, but it's really not hard. Just decide how you want to grab the user being acted upon.

Comment: Strong parameters annoy me - they feel like a hack around a refusal to rethink a bad design anti-pattern. The anti-pattern here is the use of models as the direct recipient of data from params. A pattern that solves the problem in a much cleaner way is the 'Form Object'. Luckily there are 1,000,001 gems to help you out here. And blog posts. And a pro Railscast.